# Suppressing causal tree to print in console

Tags: r, output

I am using the [causalTree](https://github.com/susanathey/causalTree) package. When I launch the `causalTree` function, something is printed in the console.

```
library(causalTree)

n <- 1000
p <- 2
y <- rnorm(n)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p)
D <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)

tree <- causalTree(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y, X), treatment = D, split.Rule = "CT", cv.option = "CT", split.Honest = T, cv.Honest = T, split.Bucket = F, xval = 5, cp = 0, minsize = 20, propensity = 0.5)

# [1] 2
# [1] "CT"
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: [not unless](https://github.com/susanathey/causalTree/blob/master/R/causalTree.R#L96:L97) you can get the authors to take your pull request, or use `capture.output` or `invisible`. it looks like those lines are left from debugging, I don't see any use for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `causalTree` has multiple `print` statements. You can prevent this to use `invisible(capture.output(...))` like this:

```r
library(causalTree)

n <- 1000
p <- 2
y <- rnorm(n)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p)
D <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)

invisible(capture.output(tree <- causalTree(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y, X), 
                                           treatment = D, split.Rule = "CT", 
                                           cv.option = "CT", split.Honest = T, 
                                           cv.Honest = T, split.Bucket = F, xval = 5, 
                                           cp = 0, minsize = 20, propensity = 0.5)))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>